# How to import Data from a Excel to dataset in asp.net page in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a excel sheet which contain records more than  20,000 records and i want to get those data in to a dataset or to a datatable in  a very  efficient and fast way to in order to process my data. please does any one know how to do this using C# code...

Comment: this is not related to asp.net-mvc. It is webforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. There is a dll called `Excel.dll [2.0.1.0] ExcelDataReader`. I do not have the link with me, since I got it from one of my friends. I think you can search it from the net and download the `exceldatareader.dll`

```
IExcelDataReader iExcelDataReader = null;

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FpdUnConLoanUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
string file = fileInfo.Name;

if (file.Split('.')[1].Equals("xls"))
{
    iExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(oStream);
}
else if (file.Split('.')[1].Equals("xlsx"))
{
    iExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(oStream);
}

iExcelDataReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet dsUnUpdated = new DataSet();
dsUnUpdated = iExcelDataReader.AsDataSet();
iExcelDataReader.Close();
if (dsUnUpdated != null)
{
}
else
{
    lblCmnMesage.Text = "No Data Found In The Excel Sheet!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static DataSet exceldata(string filelocation)

{

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

 string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filelocation + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""";

OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);

excelConn.Open();

DataTable dtPatterns = new DataTable();excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT `PATTERN` as PATTERN, `PLAN` as PLAN FROM [PATTERNS$]", excelConn);

excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;

excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatterns);

"dtPatterns.TableName = Patterns";

ds.Tables.Add(dtPatterns);

return ds;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are surprised with the count 20000. That's not a big count. You can use http://openxmldeveloper.org/ to import and process efficiently without having any dependencies on interop. Only constraint is you need to have the excel in xlsm format(Excel macros)